# Permit a role to be assumed by users belonging to a group with a IAM policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I'm trying to setup a policy for a AWS IAM Role to limit assuming the role to a specific group, but I wasn't able to find how to do it ( or if it's not possible ) from googling and the AWS Documentation.

I'm creating a role ( called **ops** ) which will be used by humans to perform operations on the AWS infrastructure. Our requirement is that multi-factor is enabled to get to this role ( even from CLI or API ).
My further requirement would be to permit assuming the role only to users belonging to a specific group ( called **operators** ).

The policy attached to **ops** that I currently developed is this ( account number replaced ):

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17", 
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole", 
            "Effect": "Allow", 
            "Condition": {
                "Bool": {
                    "aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent": "true"
                }
            }, 
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:root"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I add a further condition to restrict assuming this role only to **operators**?

Is this even possible?

Thank you!